# iOS Keychain -- how can I assure persistence on device/simulator?

Tags: ios, persistence, keychain

Environment: iOS 4.0+

**Scenario**: using KeychainItemWrapper from Apple's GenericKeychain example; iOS Simulator.

**Problem**: I can store/retrieve keychain data whilst in the debugger. But once I log out of debugger, I lose the keychain data once I return. That is, I lose access to my keychain data upon application relaunch.

This doesn't happen with Apple's GenericKeychain example.
I peeked into keychain's db via SQLiteManager and notice that the GenericKeychain example has a certificate.

**Question:** Is a certificate ***required*** to make keychain data multi-session *persistent*?